# Bigcommerce API PHP

Tags: php, doctrine, bigcommerce

I want to add products in bigcommerce store using bigcommerce Api PHP.

My code is like below:

```
$fields = array( "name" => "Apple" );
BigCommerce_Api::createBrand($fields);
```

store is connected successfully but products are not creating.Please help...

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are creating a brand and not a product. If you want to create a product, you can do something like below -

```
$filter = array('name' => 'iPhone sticker', 'price' => '12.99', 'categories' => array(2), 'type' => 'physical', 'availability' => 'available', 'weight' => 0);
$product = Bigcommerce_Api::createProduct($filter);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$new_product = new Bigcommerce_Api_Product();
$new_product->name = $_POST['name'];
$new_product->type= "type";
$product = $new_product->create();
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create brand by using xml,please check below code :

```
BigCommerce_Api::useXml();
$xml = '<brand>
          <name>'.$product[brand_name].'</name>
       </brand>';
$brand_exe = BigCommerce_Api::createBrand($xml);
```

Comment: Well, XML is not the only way. It is not required to use XML. You can create the products via JSON as well.